# How to get data from list type in the transferred object? (RealmSwift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have a realm database model object that I transfer from one controller to another. On another controller, I need to get data from this object, which stores the object of the type List. I need it in 'cellForRowAt' method.

This is my model:

```swift
class Route: Object {

    @objc dynamic var routeImage: Data?
    @objc dynamic var routeName: String?
    @objc dynamic var numberOfPersons = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var dateOfDeparture: String?
    @objc dynamic var dateOfArrival: String?
    let placeToVisit = List<Place>()
    let person = List<Person>()
}

class Place: Object {
    @objc dynamic var placeName = ""

    convenience init(placeName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.placeName = placeName
    }
}
```

on second VC I created:

```swift
var currentRoute: Route?
```

and in viewDidLoad I set:

```swift
currentRoute = UserSelectedRoute.shared.selectedRoute!
```

I can get data from other properties but not from the list type. I tried to implement 'reduce' method, but it doesn't work. It returns list type too. I think I need convert list to type Results but I don't know how I can return values from current object? 
[cellForRowAt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihxkp.png)

Comment: There's not enough code here to understand the use case. For example, what is this `UserSelectedRoute.shared.selectedRoute! ` is that a singleton? It's capitalized so should we assume it's not a class var? If it is a singleton, then there would be no need to 'pass' the object since it would be available throughout the app. Can you clarify what your asking and trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it is singleton. There is an object that is used in another controller and I need to extract it for the method 'cellForRowAt'. In picture you can see how I get data from 'dateOfDeparture' and 'dateOfArrival' - it is simple properties of database model. But I cannot get data from 'placeToVisit' to tableView.section 0. There are some objects, that I need to show.

Comment: One use of a Singleton is to have a centralized location of certain data or functions. If you are getting data from that singleton in one viewController, that same data would be available in any viewController from the singleton which means it would not need to be passed since it's available throughout the app. You do not need to 'convert' a List to Results - Lists work just fine as a dataSource. Please do not include links or screenshots of code - if that link breaks it invalidates the question. Include the code IN your question (as text) that's you are having difficulty with.

Comment: well I will consider for the future.  thanks for the advice :) then I have a question how to get objects from the list type into the table section (what I need to do in cellForRow method in secondVC and how?). a collection of the List type stores objects of the type ‘Place’ that has the property ‘namePlace’ and I need to get these objects and put them In the rows. It is a main question, please help me)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to access the List property of a Realm object. Take a look a the documentation [Many To Many](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-one) for an example of implementing List on an object. The list works very much like an array and can be iterated over or the objects can even be directly accessed via an index. In your case I don't know what the specific issue is but if you include code in your question that you're having an issue with we may be able to craft a specific answer. Oh - this works 'let place = someRouteObject.placeToVisit[4]` for example

Comment: Thank you so much)) Finally it worked, I did the following:
cell.textLabel!.text = currentRoute?.placeToVisit[indexPath.row].placeName

Answer (score 0):

As [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851937/jay) suggested to me, the following solution helped me:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = currentRoute?.placeToVisit[indexPath.row].placeName
```